# How to get Videos from flicker using api?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have developed a mobile application using `ionic framework`. In this application I am fetching the images from [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com) and showing them on a page in my application by using the API provided by flicker.

Now I am trying to fetch the videos from [flickr](http://www.flickr.com) using their API but I am unable to get the source of the video and hence not able to show that on my application.

Comment: What you have tried? show me code sample?

Comment: refer this http://code.flickr.net/2008/05/01/videos-in-the-flickr-api/

Comment: In the link video is not shown. I am also  facing the same problem